# jQuery hide parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
 <div class="windowtemplate movingwindow" style="display: block;">
    <div class="top">Attenzione <a href="#" onclick="closedialog();"><span class="closebutton"></span></a></div>
    <div class="body">
      <p>texthere</p>
      <a href="#" onclick="closedialog();"><span class="genericbutton">Close</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
 </div>
```

I'm trying to hide this box (starting from div class="windowtemplate movingwindow") with jQuery with this code:

```
function closedialog() {
           $(this).parent("windowtemplate").hide();
    };
```

But this doesn't sort any effect, where i'm wrong?
(I'm a newbie with jQuery, so, sorry if it's a really simple problem, but I can't find any solution!)

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  <a href="#" onclick="closedialog(this);"><span class="genericbutton">Close</span></a>
```

and this for your js

```
function closedialog(element) {
       $(element).closest(".windowtemplate").hide();
};
```

Comment: Works like a charm! (and is relative to my necessity) :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you missed the dot signifying a class and second parent() selector searches only level up in the tree, you need [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).
Use this code -

```
$('.genericbutton').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents(".windowtemplate").hide();
}
```

Comment: the window doesn't have parents. :)

Comment: Corrected, but nothing... :(

Comment: @MattiaDelFranco have you wrapped all this inside document.ready?

Answer (score 1):

1. `this` here doesn't refer to the clicked element.
2. The selector is wrong, missing `.` for the class selector.
3. `.parent()` doesn't select the grandparent elements, you should use `.closest()` instead.
4. You should avoid using attribute event handlers.

   ```
   $('.genericbutton').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.windowtemplate').hide();
   });
   ```

If the `.windowtemplate` is generated dynamically you should delegate the event, if you are using jQuery 1.7+ you can use the `.on()` method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.genericbutton', function() {
   $(this).closest('.windowtemplate').hide();
});
```

Comment: I can't avoid to use attribute event handlers because these boxes will be random and buttons wouldn't ever have the same function (this code is destined to a browser game), so i prefer the onclick to save some lines of code...